# Are daily steps count written to Google Fit API without Google Fit app?

Tags: android, google-fit

I'm developing an app that read Google Fit OS layer data (local data written on the phone, not Google Fit application itself).

Does phone's steps sensor natively write daily steps count to Google Fit API or is this only achieved by a tierce application (Google Fit app or any basic pedometer application) ?

Answer (score 1):

When you read the [definition](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/#read-sensor-data):

> The [Sensors API](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/sensors) provides access to raw sensor data streams from
> sensors available on the Android device and from sensors available in
> companion devices, such as wearables.

So, from that statement, it is clearly stated that the sensor from Android device and companion devices (wearables) was used and only accessed by the app when called.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you share the related url that contains the definition above?

Comment: The statement was mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/#read-sensor-data). I've also added it on the answer.